# configure multiple servers and scale

Tags: automation

I have been given a task configure 1000 of servers with some simple data. Lets say I need to login to server (linux or windows) and setup the ntp server. I need to come up with some kind of automation framework using perl. I have some ideas and want to get more.

Here is my thought process:

```
a) Since there are 1000s of servers, definitely the framework should be able to read in a csv file so all inputs can be provided as apposed to single input.

b) Since there are so many servers, I have to find a way to do things in parallel. I cant go server by server in a sequential way

c) I should have some output file that shows the results of all the servers that I successfully configured, servers that failed. That way I can compare input file and output file and generate a report
```

Should I consider anything else in my framework ?
How can I do parallel processing using perl ?

Comment: Why do you have to do it in perl, and not just use any of the existing server orchestration frameworks out there, like chef (http://www.opscode.com/chef/) or puppet (http://puppetlabs.com/)?

Comment: sounds a bit OT, have you tried superuser / http://stackexchange.com/sites#

Comment: Unfortunately, we have a lot perl coders in our group and dont want use any other language or tool (if possible).

Answer (score 0):

Even if you want to stick with Perl, it looks like there are already some alternatives available that would keep you from implementing another framework from scratch.

Check out the comments from http://my.opera.com/cstrep/blog/2010/05/14/puppet-fabric-and-a-perl-alternative for a couple options.